# Sync a local file with server to be served

Tags: nginx, synchronization

I have a little website which serves a pdf file using nginx. I change the file once a week and I need it to sync with the file that's on the server. My approach was using scp (ssh), however, I can only upload the file into admin's home directory, while it requires to be put into /var/www. Is there any practical and safe way of doing it? I thought about setting up a cron job that'd just copy it from home to /var/www, but I'm concerned whether it's safe to do so or whether it's considered to be a "bad practice". What would be your suggestion?

Comment: *Why* can't you scp straight to `/var/www/`?

Comment: root can copy anywhere, so why you cant do it?

Comment: I can't access root with SSH, it's possible only with sudo, but afaik, scp can't use sudo command.

Comment: Change permissions or add user to an appropriate group?